# Hadoop Wordcount Example with multiple files and kill mappers in it

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have 3 input files : file1.txt , file2.txt, file3.txt. file1.txt contains some error data. When i submit these files in MapReduce job 3 mappers will be created. 
Now i need to kill the mapper which contains the error file called file1.txt. After killing the mapper i want the error file to be discarded from the mapper and store in it hdfs.
How can i kill the mapper and discard the file??
And if i kill the mapper the remaining mapper should complete their process and entire job should be complete . Please help

Comment: What will you achieve by killing the mapper? Also what do you mean by "i want the error file to be discarded from the mapper and store in it hdfs"?

Comment: Suppose the error file contains "Hello World Bye World" . hence if token contains "Bye" , I want the entire file not to get parsed and the mapper containing the file should be killed. The words before or after "Bye" should not get parsed and the mapper should be killed. Rest mappers should continue their task and job should be complete

Answer (score 0):

This might not be an option approach. Store the tuples (K, V) in the map memory and emit them at the end if invalid condition is not met.

Comment: My input file size is big, which I cannot hold into the memory.

Comment: @user2991007: if your input file size (say file1.txt) is bigger than the block size, unless you are using a customInputFormat, won't you be getting more than one map task for that file?

Comment: @user2991007, can you provide the size of both file1.txt and a HDFS block?